# Retrieving results from ipyparallel when using NoDB

Tags: python, ipython

I'm using ipyparallel to run some python experiment jobs (through the epyc library), and when trying to retrieve the results (using client.result_status()) I receive a KeyError. From what I can tell, it's because the high number of jobs is causing ipyparallel to use its NoDB backend to store jobs (which causes KeyErrors when retrieving jobs at the benefit of consuming less resource - see https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/db.html).

So how do I retrieve the output from my python code?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is due to ipyparallel using NoDB as the backend when there are too many jobs. And my system using a Client to create jobs and then a separate Client to retrieve results (so I don't have to stay constantly connected). The solution is to create an iPython profile with --parallel, then edit the ipcontroller_config.py file to specify the database to use (SQLiteDB works). This persists the database in an external file and allows any client to access the results.